# Software to generate taxonomy trees

Tags: tree

Is there any software that automatically generates something like this from a list?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tools that are part of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). You would have to convert your list to the [`dot`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) language, but that's fairly simple to do.

File: list.dot

```
digraph relationship {
    One -> Parent
    Two -> Parent
    Three -> Parent
    Four -> Parent
    Five -> Parent
    Six -> Parent
    Seven -> Parent
}
```

Produce output:

```
dot -Tpng -o graphvizexample.png list.dot
```

Output:

[image: Graphviz Example]

You can do a lot of customization of the appearance. This is just a simple example.

See the Graphviz section of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4161646/26428) for another (unrelated) example.